# workaround to firefox creating new history after each document.write()

Tags: firefox, document.write

in Firefox after each document.write() new history entrie is made, so if document.write() is called on page load when user presses back button to go back in history firefox takes him to the current page which runs document.write() again and creates another history so even another back button pressing won't help and take him where he wants

simple workaround is:

```
function onbeforeunload(e) 
{
    setTimeout(function() { window.history.go(-2);  }, 0);
}
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onbeforeunload, true);
```

but then it won't let user go any link or type any address into addressbar and go there, so is there another way to fix firefox?

a better way would be to use `onpopstate` event instead but it does not work in firefox after document.write()

and no, document.write() **must be** used here.

Comment: A possible solution would be the use of DOM functionality (`getElementById`, `appendChild`, ...) instead of `document.write(...)`.

Comment: document.write must be used here.

Answer (score 5):

Use `document.open("text/html", "replace")` instead of just `document.open()`.

Works like a charm.

Interesting to note that other workarounds did NOT work - such as `$('html').replaceWith(pageContent)` or manipulating the history if the browser is Firefox...

Comment: This worked for me: `document.open("text/html", "replace"); document.write(html); document.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.open` to run `document.write` while keeping the history unchanged:

```
<script>
  document.open("text/html",document.write("foo") );
</script>
```

**References**

- [DOM document.open](http://developers.whatwg.org/webappapis.html#dom-document-open)

Comment: gilad barner, that did not work for me too, but where is your comment of what worked for you?

Comment: Didn't work for me... What *does* work is using `document.open("text/html", "replace")` instead of just `document.open()` (see my answer above) :-)